# "CAssetManager.basePath "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/instastrm/assets" is invalid

Tags: php, apache, yii

I downloaded [this](https://github.com/hunyoboy/instastrm) GitHub project. But when I put it in my XAMPP and run it, at first it shows a error like this:

> Warning: require_once(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/instastrm/../framework/yii.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/instastrm/index.php on line 13
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/instastrm/../framework/yii.php'
>   (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php') in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/instastrm/index.php on line 13

I fixed it by downloading [yii framework 1.1.16](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/releases/download/1.1.16/yii-1.1.16.bca042.tar.gz) and putting the `framework` folder into the root directory of the app and tweaking the file location in `index.php`. The above error vanished but a new one took its place but since I am new to `Yii` I don't know how to address the below error.

> CException
>
> CAssetManager.basePath
>   "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/instastrm/assets" is invalid.
>   Please make sure the directory exists and is writable by the Web
>   server process.

Comment: Look at the error it says it all `Please make sure the directory exists and is writable by the Web server process`. Provide write permissions to the `assets` folder, if it doesn't exist then create one.

Comment: @Criesto No such folder existed in the source project. So I created a folder called "/assets" but to no avail. I also set its permission to both read & write on mac. Where could I be missing out?? Was putting the framework folder into the source project really necessary? And is it the correct way to do it?

Comment: its not necessary, but you should move the framework folder inside your project folder and change the `index.php` file accordingly. You should also give write permission to `/protected/runtime/application.log`

Comment: @Criesto Can you try it on your system and let me know how really to make it work? That would be a great help to me (if not everyone)? I am failing time and again here.

Comment: works perfectly for me

Comment: You used XAMPP? After downloading what changes did you make? Still am unable to make it work.

Comment: I have pointed out all the steps that I took to run the application in my answer, check it out.

Comment: @Criesto I understand this isn't a place to ask to solve petty personal errors but I am still stuck. What you suggested below I had already done before but I since then I've been getting this error 'Error 500
CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection.' Why & how to fix it??

Comment: @Criesto and by the way I am using XAMPP and I put the whole thing in htdocs/ folder.

Comment: I have updated my answer, I would recommend that you go through the yii guides first, I have also posted a link which you might find helpful. cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Download the project you're installing from [here](https://github.com/hunyoboy/instastrm/archive/master.zip).
Download `Yii 1.1.16` from [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/releases/download/1.1.16/yii-1.1.16.bca042.tar.gz).

- Extract the project folder inside `/var/www` folder, your folder structure should look like `/var/www/instastrm-master/`, you can rename this if you want.
- Now, extract the `yii-1.1.16.bca042.tar.gz` that you downloaded earlier and copy `framework` folder and paste it inside `/var/www/instastrm-master/`.
- Modify your `index.php` file, which you will find in
  `/var/www/instastrm-master/index.php` and change the line:

  `$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../framework/yii.php';`

  to

  `$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/framework/yii.php';`
- Create an `assets` folder inside `/var/www/instastrm-master/`, and give the entire folder read write permission (777).
- Create another folder inside `/var/www/instastrm-master/protected/` called `runtime` and give it the read write permission too.
- Try executing the application, `http://localhost/instastrm-master`, it should work.

**Edit:**

After looking at your comments on `Error 500 CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection.`, this error means the applcation cannot connect to the database, I don't exactly know your project details, I went through the `models` in `/protected/models/`, I guess you'll have to create the following tables:

1. `media`, with fields `id, name`
2. `media_details` with fields `id, tag_id, media_url, display_url, text, profile_image_url, username, media_id, media_type_id, unique_identifier`
3. `media_type` with fields `id, name`
4. `tags` with fields `id, name, unix_time`

and then modify your projects `/protected/config/main.php` file to connect to your database, like:

```
'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=<your_database_name>',
            'emulatePrepare' => true, 
            'username' => 'db_username',
            'password' => 'db_password',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),
```

Note: change `db` params according to your need.

I would recommend that you go through the official `yii` guides first and learn how `yii` works, you could also refer to [Larry Ullman yii series](http://www.larryullman.com/series/learning-the-yii-framework/) which explains everything step by step.

Hope that helps.